# Android is possible include .aar with activity extends Application?

Tags: android, aar, altbeacon

I have an Android project, inside I have a library module, my project works fine, compile the project I get the .aar included in a test project and everything ok.
Now,I have added in my library module a Activity that extends Application, Y Added this class in the manifiest.xml of the library

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MyActivityExtendsApplications"
```

When I test the project it works perfect, but when I take the .aar and test it on other project fails. The problem is that it does not find the activity extend Application ... I have decompiled the aar and I see that everything is correct, all class are inside the folder 
The error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mylibrary.MyActivityExtendsApplications" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapplication-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapplication-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mylibrary.MyActivityExtendsApplications
                      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                            ... 12 more
                   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

I adding grandle dependency to library .aar In all cases in the same way

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'mylibrary-debug.mylibrary-debug@aar'

}
repositories{
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'

    }
}
```

I check merged manifest in my test Project and the activity is there

```
application
        android:name="com.mylibrary.MyActivityExtendsApplications"
        android:allowBackup="true"
```

And I can import this Activity in my test Project and see the code

And I added mylibrary in libs folder.
When I remove the activity MyActivityExtendsApplications, my library works fine.

Comment: what is that you are aiming by having an Activity extending an Application?

Comment: Hi @petrumo, I need this, because my aar implements http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html, and I need starting in background

Comment: Wow, I am surprised that an Activity is even able to extend Application.  This is certainly not the intended usage of the Android Beacon Library for background launching.   I don't want to sidetrack this question with this unusual Application usage issue, but I am happy to address it in a different question if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may be the the Android Beacon Library aar files are missing when you generate your library aar, and the exception description is simply misleading. I don't think classes from aar files are automatically merged when generating a new aar file.  You might check to see if these files (like Beacon.class) are missing from your aar.

If this is indeed the problem, there are two possible solutions:

- In your application, reference *both* your library aar file and the Android Beacon Library aar file.
- Merge the classes from the first aar file into your new aar file.  I have done this before with rather a rather inelegant shell script that I am happy to share, but there may be a better way to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Thanks so much, @davidgyoung, I assumed that just as the .aar includes the manifest.xml, I also included the build.grandle that was generated when creating a library module with android studio. My Error,I did not realize that your  project classes are not included. On the other hand, is there no possibility of doing an .aar with a build.grandle that merges with the build.grandle of the target project? Something similar to the .framework of IOS, in the resources that can add resources to its library .Thank, for your help, and I take this opportunity to congratulate by your extraordinary library

Comment: Yeah, I don't know of any way to do this automatically in Gradle or Android Studio, but I haven't researched it in a year or more.  Here is the hacky shell script that I came up with to solve the problem for me.  This was based on a library project that had the Android Beacon Library as a subproject one level down inside its root directory.  Use this script at your own risk!  https://gist.github.com/davidgyoung/aada365eeb69db12027532c32243674f

Comment: Thanks so much by the script, @davidgyoung, You helped me so much today and weeks ago when made my app for IOS and I searched info about ibeacon protocol and I found yours explications to others guys. thanks :)